# traversing through multi dimension array

Tags: python

I have a dataset that has time, longitude, latitude. I want to perform a function at every grid point.

this is what my dataset looks like:
time:29 lat: 4 lon: 8

for all time (29 days). at every lonxlat there is 29 values (29 days)
I am unable to extract data at those coordinate

I tried this

```
for x in range(len(m.lon)):
    for y in range(len(m.lat)):
        mhws, clim = mhw.detect(t_x, m.sst[:][x][y],pctile=90,alternateClimatology=[t_c,sst_c] )
```

for every lon[x] x lat[y] I want to extract the timeseries of data (in this case it should around 29 unique days of data) at that intersection and feed it to the the function in the nested for loop

Comment: Please explain what "unable to do this means". Does your code work but not as expected. Are you receiving an error message, if so, please post the error message and where it's occurring. Also a reproducible example is needed to help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please give more information about what your data actually looks like/what type of object it is held in? Is it stored in in a Python dictionary, a Pandas dataframe, or some more complex data type?

Comment: Thank you. It looks like you're using the marineHeatWaves package. Are you able to post a minimal reproducible example so we can help. We have no way of knowing what your data is, i.e. (t_x, t_c, sst_c, m.sst).